# the distribution of Singular value of rectangular gaussian matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

the singular value decomposition of an $m\times n$ random Gaussian matrix ${\displaystyle \mathbf {M} }$  is a factorization of the form ${\displaystyle \mathbf {U\Sigma V^\ast} }$,  ${\displaystyle \mathbf {\Sigma } }$ is an ${\displaystyle m\times n}$ rectangular diagonal matrix with non-negative ordred real numbers on the diagonal, my question is:

What is the distribution of the singular values of $\Sigma $?

can I say that the singular value corresponds to the absolute value of Gaussian variable?

Answer (score 3):

With fixed ratio $\lambda=m/n$ the [Marchenko-Pastur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) distribution gives the asymptotic distribution of singular values for a Gaussian rectangular matrix.

The extreme singular values limiting distribution in particular is given by the [Tracy-Widom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy%E2%80%93Widom_distribution) distribution.

Also, the singular values do not have limiting distribution corresponding to the absolute value of a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: and what can I say if $m$ is fixed and $n$ is arbitrarily large?

Comment: That's not quite true. The Marchenko Pastur distribution is the limiting distribution for the singular values squared.